# Too few arguments passed with Mail::raw(), Laravel

Tags: laravel

I keep getting this error:

```
"Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\PageController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected"
```

For this little snippet of code:

```
public function contact(Request $request)  {
    Mail::raw($request->message, function($message, $request)
     {
         $message->from($request->email, $request->name);

         $message->to('info@test.com');
     });
      return view('quotation.index');  
}
```

When changing the `$request->email` to a email string the function does work. But the email needs to come from the email entered in the laravel form. Could someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: You are getting error on this line `$message->from($request->email, $request->name);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are passing variables to closure but in a wrong way.

You have to use `use ($request)` in closure if you want to pass a variable.

```
public function contact(Request $request)  {
    Mail::raw($request->message, function($message) use ($request)
     {
         $message->from($request->email, $request->name);

         $message->to('info@test.com');
     });
      return view('quotation.index');  
}
```

Hope this helps.